# Python-pycharm-oemof: Attribute Error with processing.results()

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a problem with executing the function processing.results() in oemof.
It was working before, but after an update it didn't work any more.
Does anyone know how to fix it or which interpreter I need for oemof - oemof test says all is installed correct. Or is my code wrong?

Code:

```
64/# OPTIMIZATION MODEL
65/equipmentList = (electricity_bus, heat_bus, electricity_grid, electricity_supply, 
   electricity_storage, heat_supply, heat_storage, heat_pump, photovoltaics, excess_electricity)
66/for item in equipmentList:
67/    optimizationSystem.add(item)
68/model = solph.Model(optimizationSystem)
69/model.write('optimizationSystem_model.lp', io_options={'symbolic_solver_labels': True})
70/model.solve(solver='gurobi', solve_kwargs={'tee': True})
71/results = solph.processing.results(model)
```

Failure-Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/TKurz/Desktop/NEFI Hackathon/Main.py", line 71, in <module>
    results = solph.processing.results(model)
  File "C:\Users\TKurz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\oemof\solph\processing.py", line 125, in results
    df = create_dataframe(om)
  File "C:\Users\TKurz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\oemof\solph\processing.py", line 89, in create_dataframe
    for i in getattr(bv, "_index"):
AttributeError: 'IndexedVar' object has no attribute '_index'
```

THX for any help!
Yours Thomas

Comment: Sorry, the code formate didn't work well...
64/;65 etc. should be the number of the lines

Comment: THX buhtz for editing!